# SQL Server 2005 Agent running SSIS job can't find file path

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server, paths

Basically I'm trying to run a functioning SSIS job (created in BIDS) under the SQL Server Agent - it reads a set of Excel spreadsheets and dumps the results into a table.
The problem I'm having is getting the SSA to read the file path, the relevant part of the error is:

"0x80004005  Description: "'N:\Assets Property & Facilities Management\Monthly Absence.xls' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."

I've tried using UNC paths (\servername\ share) but the BIDS rewrites the paths to standard file paths (c:\directory\filename), I've also tried a proxy which runs this step under an Admin account.  I've also tried changing the path to UNC on the SSIS job on the server.  Also I'm forcing it to use the 32 bit DTEXEC, so it's not that either

Always get the same error, do I need to re-create the job from scratch?

Comment: I've found out how to get rid of this error - basically create a new connection an that allows you to use a UNC rather than a standard file path.  Now I'm getting permissions failures!
*SIGH*

'\\data3-w\sqlhr\Assets Property & Facilities Management\Monthly Absence.xls'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.".  0xC020801C

Comment: Did you get rid of this permission error? I'm facing with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out how to get rid of this error - basically create a new connection an that allows you to use a UNC rather than a standard file path. 
I've also found out how to use cmexec to run a 32 bit job, now I just need to figure out how to run the job under the SQL Server agent so that it actually produces some output!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account running SQL Server agent has rights to the path specified.
e.g. if SQL Server agent service is running under domain\account1 then domain\account1 has proper rights to access the file system(path specified in package).

Comment: It's running from an admin account, so it can see the drive, I'm pretty sure.